# Remove incomplete ISO dates from SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, date, iso

I am writing an application in Perl to handle data from a MySQL database. I need to select only records that have a valid ISO format date, YYYY-MM-DD. However a lot of the records don't have a value for the month or day, so they are like this 1999-00-00. I need to filter these out.

I could do it with Perl, but I think the best way to do it would be to use the REGEXP function in the SQL statement; however I'm not sure if this is the best way; nor do I know how I would regex the data.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Once you do so, think about storing dates as dates and not strings.

Comment: @DanBracuk: mysql allows storing partial dates in its date fields, where any of the parts may 0.  this is occasionally convenient, and often not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just use:

```
where DATE_COL not like '%-00-00'
```

Comment: or `where year(DATE_COL) and month(DATE_COL) and dayofmonth(DATE_COL)`